# How do I calculate this inverse Laplace Transform

Tags: control-system, transfer-function, pid-controller, laplace-transform

I have this transfer function and input, and I have to manually calculate what the systems response will be.
The transfer function is:

[image]

and the input is:

[image]

I multiplied the two functions and used fraction decomposition by partial fraction expansion and calculated the inverse laplace transform and this is what I got:

[image]

But the response I get from that function does not correspond to the one I get using matlab. This is the matlab code I used:

```
t=0:0.1:100;
FT6=tf(0.1,[1 1 0.1])
r=4*sin(10*t);
V=lsim(FT6,r,t);
plot(t,V,'-')
```

How do I calculate it properly by hand?

[image]

Comment: You have a transfer function in the Laplace domain, and an input signal in the time domain -- did you just multiply \$FT_6(s)\$ to \$r(t)\$, or did you take the Laplace transform of r(t)?

Comment: I took the laplace transform of r(t), I forgot to mention it

Comment: Please show more of your work; that may help to pinpoint where the problem lies.

Comment: Whatever else is going on, you've got a 2nd-order lowpass filter that's excited by a signal that starts at zero (i.e. \$ r(0) = 0\$).  So you would expect that not only the response, but its first two derivatives would be zero at \$t = 0\$.  Yet your result has an initial value that is not zero.

Comment: I included my calculations, I hope you can understand my writing

Comment: https://www.symbolab.com/solver/inverse-laplace-calculator/inverse%20laplace%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Cleft(s%5E%7B2%7D%2B100%5Cright)%5Cleft(s%5E%7B2%7D%2Bs%2B0.1%5Cright)%7D

Comment: @Andyaka nice find!  Doing it with cosh and sinh is -- uh -- interesting.

Comment: @TimWescott try this: http://math2.org/math/trig/hyperbolics.htm

Comment: I know what hyperbolics *are*.  I've just never seen them used that way before -- and I've done a *lot* of control system design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you have
\begin{equation}
R(s) = \frac{40}{s^2+10^2}
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
Y(s) = FT_6(s)R(s)=\frac{4}{(s^2+10^2)(s^2+s+0.1)}
\end{equation}
Then you proceed by taking partial fractions of Y(s)
\begin{equation}
Y(s) = \frac{A+sB}{(s^2+10^2)} +\frac{C+sD}{(s^2+s+0.1)}
\end{equation}
Then you expand the term
\begin{equation}
\frac{C+sD}{s^2+s+0.1} = \frac{C+sD}{(s+\frac{1}{2})^2-0.15} = 
D\frac{s+\frac{1}{2}}{(s+\frac{1}{2})^2-0.15} +
(C-\frac{D}{2})\frac{1}{(s+\frac{1}{2})^2-0.15}
\end{equation}
Now you can use a [table](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Laplace_Table.pdf) (keeping in mind the table items 7,8,21 and 22).